# "Select all, excluding" selector in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a DIV that contains many child elements like e.g. other DIVs, SPANs and links.

Is it possible to specify in JQuery selector that I want to call a function whenever an element of this DIV (including the DIV itself) is clicked, with the exception of all links (`a`), where this function should not be called?

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730609/using-jquery-not-selector-to-exclude-elements-with-particular-children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of selecting all and excluding some elements and bind event handlers to each of them, the easier way (imo) would be to attach the event handler just to the `div` and test whether a link was clicked or not (*event delegation*):

```
$('#yourDiv').click(function(event) {
    if(event.target.nodeName !== 'A') {
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```

This would only work if the links don't have any other elements as children.

More robust might be using [`.delegate` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and the [`:not` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo selector:

<del>$('#yourDiv').delegate(':not(a)', 'click', function(event) {
        // do your stuff
    });</del>

**Update:** Apparently, you have to add another `click` event handler to the `div` to be able to detect clicks on the `div` itself (my tests with using the delegate selector only failed):

```
$('#yourDiv')
 .delegate(':not(a)', 'click', handler)
 .click(function(event) {
     if(event.target === this) {  // only if the `div` was clicked
         handler.apply(this, arguments);
     }
 });
```

Here, `handler` is the actual event handler you want to execute. By using an extra function, you don't have to repeat the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div#div_id, div#div_id *:not(a)').click(function(){
    // do whatever you like here
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/fG8sj/)

Comment: Yeah I guessed it... sometimes I'm too quick with commenting :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery `not()` method to achieve what you are looking for.

e.g.

```
$('div, div *').not('a').click(function(){
    //handle click  
});
```

alternately you could use the `:not()` selector

e.g.

```
$('div, div *:not(a)').click(function(){
    //handle click  
});
```

But I personally find the first method more readable and prettier.

Comment: This does not include the `div` itself.

Comment: amended to include the div, I missed that part of his question

Answer (score 1):

You could use the the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method to exclude elements.